# Prepend Qt Creator .config to .h with imported makefile

Tags: c++, c, qt, makefile

As I understand it, when developing C++ in Qt Creator with a generated makefile, the .config file is transparently prepended to each .h file.

Let's say the .config file lives in the root directory, and we have directories for src/ and inc/ under that. The .config file is basically just a list of `#define` constants. One normally does not have to explicitly `#include` it.

What is the best way to emulate this in a custom (imported) makefile, so that the .config file is not explicitly included in each .h?

Thanks for any help.

Snippet of my current src/makefile:

```
VALID_TOOLCHAINS := pnacl
NACL_SDK_ROOT ?= $(abspath ../../prg/nacl_sdk/pepper_canary)
include ../common.mk

APP_SOURCES = Common.cc App.cc MoreMath.cc AppGraph.cc AppAudio.cc Noise.cc

TARGET = nim
INC_PATHS = $(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/include ../inc
LIBS = ppapi_gles2 ppapi_cpp ppapi pthread
CFLAGS = -Wall
SOURCES =  $(APP_SOURCES) Neonim.cc
# Build rules generated by macros from common.mk:
$(foreach src,$(SOURCES),$(eval $(call COMPILE_RULE,$(src),$(CFLAGS))))
ifeq ($(CONFIG),Release)
$(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET)_unstripped,$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
$(eval $(call STRIP_RULE,$(TARGET),$(TARGET)_unstripped))
else
$(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET),$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
endif
$(eval $(call NMF_RULE,$(TARGET),))
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Also `./` and `../` are not the same thing.

Comment: Agree with @EtanReisner, clarify your question.

Comment: What you mean, "prepend .config"? What exactly is prepending what here?

Answer (score 1):

It is usually [qmake](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-manual.html) that generates the makefile when we deal with Qt, no matter if we use Qt Creator or not. qmake consumes MyAppProjectFile.pro file with all the project files, compiler and linker options, pre- and post- build steps listed there. Start from the link pointing to qmake. As soon as you get the idea how the Qt project is organized you will probably ask us more "detailed" question so we'd be able to understand that and answer it better.

When I studied Qt some years ago I went through Qt examples and compiled them from command line and tried to change that code. Setting up command line environment for building Qt apps and examples will be a very good exercise. You will also be able to build your own project create in Qt creator but from command line -- that is really easy and enlightens a lot in the field of what files used, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the considered response. This is my first question on SO, so I did a lot of question editing.

Comment: I am not using qmake, but an imported makefile for my C++ project that I do not want edited by Qt Creator.

Comment: Read on qmake, jom, and compiler tools. First 2 are parts of Qt and jom is an equivalent to make. Compiler tools can be applied to Qt project and you need to provide an environment e.g. paths, INCLUDE LIBS vars e.g. from vcvars32 or vcvarsall.bat for Visual Studio or the default compiler tools usually configured by default on Linux/Unix/Mac OS but you will probably need to set up specific ones. Until you understand some basics it is hard for us to *really* help you.

Comment: Qt Creator is integrated with qmake by default. It uses qmake and compiler tools configured. Period.

Comment: It's been working fine for me - have a python script that configures it for whichever platform I'm on. I just don't know much about make files, so was wondering how to emulate that .config behavior. In the end, it's sounding like it's just better to include it in each header file. More portable that way anyhow.